# Do other Chasidic communities follow Shulchan Aruch HaRav?

Tags: halacha, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, shulchan-aruch

The Maggid of Mezeritch told the Baal HaTanya to put together [a Shulchan Aruch for Chasidim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch_HaRav#New_version_of_the_Shulchan_Aruch).  The result is the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, which is used as a final authority for halacha in Chabad communities in most cases.  [Wikipedia asserts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch_HaRav#Influence) that it is used as such by "most Hasidim", but in my experience I have not seen it on the shelves of Chasidic shuls or batei midrash.

Do any other communities rely on it as a final authority rather than the Mechaber, the Rema, the Mishna Berura, the Kitzur, etc.?

Which communities rely on which other texts is also interesting.

Comment: Very few communities rely exclusively upon a single text. All Orthodox communities treat the Shulchan Arukh haRav as authoritative, but only Lubavitchers will ever treat it as ultimately authoritative. That is not to say that Lubavitchers will avoid studying other works. They treat it as many Litvaks treat the Mishne Berurah: authoritative to the point of being the final word, though not the only opinion. Likewise, many Sephardim now treat the halakha of the mechaber in a similar fashion (based upon the exhortations of Rav Ovadiah).

Comment: @ShimonbM that's a good point.  I guess the question is more specifically whether other Chasidic communities regard it as a final authority. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: No need to edit: I think your question is already well-phrased. Just wanted to add my two cents :)

Comment: @ShimonbM thanks! But I'll keep the edit because it makes for a more specific question.

Comment: I understand that a number of rabbis rule like the _SA Harav_ in _Yore Dea_, treating him as the _posek acharon_ for that _tur_, or at least in many cases. I'm not sure that this is hasidic rabbis specifically. In any event, I have no good source for this, so am not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @yoel I saw in Karlin-Stolin of Monsey that they advertised in their Beis Medrash to learn Halachah Lma'aseh - Shulchan Aruch Harav, every day at a certain time, and they printed packets of the text for people to use.

Comment: [Rav Shemerler](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%A8) (one of the administrators of Mifal HaShas and a Tzanzer Chossid) organized a program called "[Shaarei Horaah](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94)" where [hundreds](http://www.col.org.il/news_print.rtx?artID=28686) of people take tests on the Shulchan Aruch HaRav.

Comment: I heard new square Hasidim,

Comment: I have heard that Satmar Chassidim use it.

Comment: @ShimonbM lubavitchers also don't only rely on shulchan aruch harav as a single text. the siddur written and published later by the Alter Rebbe hs dinim which contradict his earlier work and is more authoritative. There are also other writings later on individual subjects which may. not have been addressed in the sidur.

Comment: user9643 I don't think so, they no longer want to have anything to do with Chabad things because they think the Rebbe is a Zionist, they were studying Tanya before but they stopped for this reason there is a letter from the Rebbe which shows his astonishment

Comment: I know that in the Mishnah brura the admour hazaken is very often brought back…