# Do all hasidim/some frum follow Shulchan aruch haRav?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, orthodox

Do all hasidim, Satmar/Chabad/Breslov etc follow the Shulchan aruch haRav? is there any hasidic group that mainly uses Mishnah Berurah for halacha lemaaseh primarily? I know frum Ashkenazim mainly use either MB or Aruch hashulchan but do some also follow S.A haRav primarily? Or is it only Chabad that follows Shulchan aruch haRav?

Comment: Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26359/6592

Comment: @shmosel Sorry i wasn't aware of that one. It's not intended to be a duplicate.

Comment: @shmosel I see that a comment there says its treated at authorative, but i'm asking about it being used primarily for halacha lemaaseh among other hasidic groups and among some frum yidden outside of Chabad.